# Remove cached searches when using a form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using this code:

```
<form action="https://google.com/search" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" />
```

To allow me to search using google from a custom homepage. But after every search it seems to be caching my search terms.

When I return to the HTML page when I click on the form it has my previous searches as auto fill drop-down box.

I'd like to disable this function and stop the page from caching.

Thank You

Comment: Also I don't have a lot of knowledge in HTML or CSS

Comment: take a look to [Turning off form autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as easy as adding autocomplete="off" to your form element.

```
<form action="https://google.com/search" method="get" autocomplete="off"></form>
```